# CORS request with GET works, but POST does not work - ASP .NET CORE and using JWT Auth

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, cors, http-headers, jwt

if I am doing a GET request, it works just fine, however, a POST request does not work. I've searched for a few hours and can't figure it out, basically every suggestion I've seen, I've already tried.

Here's my `Configure` function:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) //Remember to switch launchSettings.json to 'Production'
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

        if (IsDebug) //Allows testing by using a frontend at localhost:8080 - Configure the port to your frontend port.
        {
            app.UseCors(builder => builder
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
            );                  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });

}
```

I am registering the CORS middleware before any other.

For the methods I'm trying to call, I have `[Authorize]` placed on the class, and `[HttpPost]` placed on the methods. If I switch it to `[HttpGet]` it works.

Here's an example of how I'm calling my API:

```
var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwtToken
}

// Don't burden the server with unnecessary calls to the API if we don't even have a token.
if (jwtToken) {
    var result = await axios.post('https://localhost:44377/api/Playground/GetMenuItems', { headers: headers } );
    if (result.data === -1) { throw -1 }    
    return result.data;
}
```

This is what my Network Tools looks like:

[image]

I believe the first one is the preflight as the request method is `OPTIONS`, and it returns 204:

[image]

Here is the failed POST request, failing with 401:

[image]

Notice how the bearer token is not sent in the request. However, it is sent in the request payload.

I'm absolutely scratching my head here, I would really appreciate it if anyone has some insight!

Cheers.

P.S.  Here's my `ConfigureServices` function:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); // => remove default claims
    services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    })
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        cfg.SaveToken = true;
        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"])),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
        };
    });


    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);


    if (IsDevelopment)
    {
        IsDebug = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("DEBUGGING");
        if (IsDebug)
        {
            services.AddCors(); //Dangerous in prod.
        }

        _connectionString = Configuration["PlaygroundConnectionString"];
    }
    else
    {
        // Get prod secrets
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Axios.post` requires 3 parameters - you are only providing two. And the second parameter is the `data` object to send as the body of the `post` command, which explains why your headers are being sent in the body.

From the [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config):

> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

Try changing your code to

```
var result = await axios.post('https://localhost:44377/api/Playground/GetMenuItems', null, { headers: headers } );
```

The `Axios.get` command only required 2 parameters, which is why that one is working.

Comment: I'm such a fool. I was converting a get request to a post request, and as such only changed the method name. I naturally thought it must be CORS. Kind of an XY problem. I'll test when I'm at work tomorrow and approve your answer if it solves it. Thank you!